# Soundcloud api access Token (Oauth2)

Tags: php, api, oauth, access-token, soundcloud

### Test whit php-soundcloud

I try to use the script [php-soundcloud](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud) (Oauth 2) and I encounter a problem after user login.
I do exactly the tutorial wiki: https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud/wiki/Oauth-2

When the user has accepted the application, it returns the following URL: `http://mywebsite.com/?code=123456789123456789`

I get the correct `$_GET['code']` but the function `accessToken()` will not retrieve the information, it gives me a **HTTP code 401** error (see the picture below).

[image: HTTP code 401 soundcloud]

Here is my code (the most basic):

```
<?php

include 'Services/Soundcloud.php';
$soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud('_myClientId_', '_ClientSecret_', '_RedirectUri_');

echo '<a href="' . $soundcloud->getAuthorizeUrl() . '">Connect with SoundCloud</a><br />';

try {
    $accessToken = $soundcloud2->accessToken($_GET['code']);
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

Here is HTTP Status Codes of soundcloud: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#errors
They say that the code 401 is: Make sure you're sending us a `client_id` or `access_token`.
 But I'm sure to send the correct id and token! :/

If someone has already manipulate SoundCloud API and know why I get this error, let me know of any solution.

Comment: I don't have time right now, but I'll favorite it and help you with it tonight if you still don't have a solution. :-)

Comment: thank PeeHaa, I guess it should not be much, but I not find a solution :p

Comment: You could also check out the [OAuth library](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib) @PeeHaa has been working on. It has an implementation for SoundCloud already.

Comment: @Leigh I just try it, it work but only once... i have update my first post. I must create a cookie to keep session open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i have find! it's so easy...
I had not seen the function `setAccessToken()` which adds the token to the class

```
try {
    $accessToken = $soundcloud2->accessToken($_GET['code']);
    // this is the part that I was missing
    $soundcloud2->setAccessToken($accessToken["access_token"]);
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: How could this possible solve anything, given that the exception is thrown by the call $accessToken = $soundcloud2->accessToken($_GET['code']); ??
Calling setAccessToken after that solves nothing, as the exception is thrown before

Answer (score 0):

atmon3r's answer is certainly wrong.
The call to setAccessToken() is completely unnecessary, as the call to accessToken() already sets the access token. Also, he was getting an exception when calling accessToken(), so it's impossible that adding a line of code *after* the one  that issued the exception could fix it.

I had had the same error, and in my case **it was caused by calling the Services_Soundcloud constructor without the third (redirect_uri) parameter**. Adding this parameter (which shouldn't be necessary in the first place as it is completely useless, but the SoundCloud API is terribly designed) made it work for me (with no need to call setAccessToken).

Besides the API being ill-conceived (in that it only allows for one fixed return url configured in the application [already a stupid and crippling limitation by itself] and at the same time requires it as a parameter [when it can only have one valid value]), the PHP library is flawed, in that it won't throw an exception if you call the constructor without the third parameter which is required.

Note that the value of return_url must match the one configured in the application.